# Error code 255 when pushing to mercurial

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, eclipse-plugin, mercurialeclipse

I've setup mercurial hg on a windows server to control the source of a website I work on.

On my local machine, I can pull from the remote repository, but not push. It gives me an authentication error. authorization failed , error code : 255

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you hosting this remote repository? [This page](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories) has more information on configuring authentication for different ways of publishing repositories.

Comment: Hi, I installed TortoiseHg 2.5 with Mercurial 2.3.1 on the remote Windows server. It's serving properly, and I can pull successfully from my machine, into zend with mercurial. I can't push from my machine to the remote server though. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it's serving properly"? Are you running `hg serve` on the remote server?

Comment: Hi, yes, running hg serve via the command line via RDP. I can then pull from it from my machine at home. Thanks for your help so far. :)

Comment: Also, i've figured out, if I have [ui]
username = * in the hgrc file, I can push successfully, but if I have [ui]
username = myusername it won't allow me to push. With the authorisation failed message. In my push window, I have the username set correctly. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I meant
[web]
allow_push = *
VS
[web]
allow_push = myname

Comment: I don't think `hg serve` itself allows for finer control of users (see [this](http://selenic.com/pipermail/mercurial/2012-January/041622.html)). If you still want to try some form of user management with `hg serve`, take a look at the [hg-textauth](https://bitbucket.org/hstuart/hg-textauth) extension

Comment: I've installed textauth successfully. I'll get setting that up! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My solution!
If your are on Windows OS, you need to edit folder properties. Read/write permission.

[screenshoot folder properties example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhbCh.png)

Very Important!!
Dont forget turn off the web server, edit folder properties and turn on again the web server tortoiseHG

Comment: Small terminology correction: `Windows OS` should be just `Windows`